# how to capture all changes to the contents of a <body> element in JS

Tags: javascript, events, dom, iframe, gmail

I am trying to write an extension for Google Chrome.  I want to capture any keyboard input on a given page, and do something magic to it.  I am able to do most of what I need with these lines:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) { OnKeyDown(event); }, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) { OnKeyDown(event); }, false);
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) { OnKeyPress(event); }, false);`
```

This works in most places, except for Google Mail.  I am not getting these events when typing into the body of an email, because as it turns out, it's actually a `<body>` element, inside an `<iframe>`.

Comment: Just a note, your anonymous functions are not needed. `document.addEventListener("keydown", OnKeyDown, false)` would work the same way without the extra function.

Comment: Thanks, I have it this way because I sometimes add alert()'s or other function calls in there, for debugging and whatnot.

Comment: Eugene, I realize this is over a year old, but here I am in the same boat as were some time ago. Were you ever able to get this working? Please let us know!

Comment: No, the issue became moot for me when gmail built something similar, and even more so when I started using a Mac.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create trojan, you would better use C++, otherwise, reconcider your project/task. If project needs intercepting of all user input events in browser using JavaScript, then something is completely wrong with this project.

Comment: Thanks for the trust, but actually I am trying to create something a-la ToCyrillic for Firefox, and I'm confined to Javascript because that's all Google Chrome allows for extensions.